# Logging how many times a certain file is requested on Apache2

Tags: bash, logging, apache2

Looking for some advice here.

I know this can be done using AWStats or something similar, but that seems like overkill for what I want to do here.

I have a directory in my webroot that contains thousands of XML files.
These are all loaded by calls to a single swf file using GET requests in the url.

eg :

```
https://www.example.com/myswf.swf?url=https://www.example.com/xml/1234567.xml
```

The urls are built dynamically and there are thousands of them. All pointing to the same swf file, but pulling in a different XML file from the XML directory.

What I'm looking to do is log how many times each of those individual XML files is requested to a text file.

As I know the target directory, is there a bash script or something that I can run that will monitor the XML directory and log each hit with a timestamp?

eg :

```
1234567.xml | 1475496840
7878332.xml | 1481188213
etc etc
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are these request URLs stored?

Comment: They are on dynamically generated (wordpress) pages. They are actually OG Meta Tags for podcasts that display the swf player and it's loaded content (XML) on Facebook.

Comment: From what I understand, if you have a huge file with all the request URLs (or can append multiple files to this format), a simple `grep -c -f index file` should do. Where `index` contains all the .xml file names and `file` is a total list of all the URLs.

Comment: Hmm that's not really practical in this respect as there are new XML files being generated daily, so practically I would never have a "complete" list. Of course this could be automated to update the master file every time a new XML file is generated but it seems like a really long way round.

Comment: I'm having too much fun thinking about this problem. You might get more eyes if you add an `awk` tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler, more direct approach-

```
uniq -c requests.txt
```

Where I'm assuming all your request URLs are in a file called `requests.txt`.

Better formatted output-

```
awk -F/ '{print $8}' requests.txt | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly way since it uses loops to process text rather that an elegant `awk` array but it should work (slowly). Optimisation is definitely required.

I'm assuming all your request URLs are in a file called `requests.txt`

```
#Put all the unique URLs in an index file

awk -F/ '{print $8}' requests.txt | sort -u > index 

#Look through the file to count the number of occurrences of each item.

while read i
do 
    echo -n "$i | " 
    grep -c -w "$i" requests.txt 
done < index
```